# Can't make a zoom on D3 graph

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I tried out many ways to create a zoom to my D3 graph working with the roots.
By that I mean giving the option of zoom in and zoom out for the nodes circles from the root.

```
<style>
        .node circle {
            fill: #fff;
            stroke: steelblue;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        .node {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #ccc;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }
    </style>
```

The script:

```
<script>

    var diameter = 960;

    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .size([360, diameter / 2 - 120])
        .separation(function (a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth; });

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
        .projection(function (d) { return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI]; });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", diameter)
        .attr("height", diameter - 150)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

    d3.json("json.json", function (error, root) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
            links = tree.links(nodes);

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(links)
          .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("d", diagonal);

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(nodes)
          .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
              /*this will change the color of the class node to red*/
            .on('mouseover', function (d) {
                var nodeSelection = d3.select(this).style("fill", "red");
            })
        node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 4.5);

        node.append("text")
            .attr("dy", ".31em")
            .attr("text-anchor", function (d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "rotate(180)translate(-8)"; })
            .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

        /*try out*/

    });
</script>
```

JSON:

```
{
    "name": "flare",
    "children": [
     {
         "name": "analytics",
         "children": [
          {
              "name": "cluster",
              "children": [
               {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
               {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
               {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
               {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
              ]
          },
          {
              "name": "graph",
              "children": [
               {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
               {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
               {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
               {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
               {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
              ]
          },
          {
              "name": "optimization",
              "children": [
               {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
              ]
          }
         ]
     },
     {
         "name": "animate",
         "children": [
          {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
          {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
          {
              "name": "interpolate",
              "children": [
               {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
               {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
               {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
               {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
               {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
               {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
               {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
               {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
               {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
              ]
          },
          {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
          {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
          {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
          {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
          {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
          {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
          {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
          {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
          {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
         ]
     },
     {
         "name": "data",
         "children": [
          {
              "name": "converters",
              "children": [
               {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
               {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
               {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
               {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
               {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
              ]
          },
          {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
          {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
          {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
          {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
          {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
          {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
         ]
     },
     {
         "name": "display",
         "children": [
          {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
          {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
          {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
          {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
         ]
     },
     {
         "name": "flex",
         "children": [
          {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
         ]
     },
     {
         "name": "physics",
         "children": [
          {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
          {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
          {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
          {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
          {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
          {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
          {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
          {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
         ]
     },
     {
         "name": "query",
         "children": [
          {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
          {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
          {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
          {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
          {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
          {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
          {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
          {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
          {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
          {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
          {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
          {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
          {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
          {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
          {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
          {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
          {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
          {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
          {
              "name": "methods",
              "children": [
               {"name": "add", "size": 593},
               {"name": "and", "size": 330},
               {"name": "average", "size": 287},
               {"name": "count", "size": 277},
               {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
               {"name": "div", "size": 595},
               {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
               {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
               {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
               {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
               {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
               {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
               {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
               {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
               {"name": "max", "size": 283},
               {"name": "min", "size": 283},
               {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
               {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
               {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
               {"name": "not", "size": 386},
               {"name": "or", "size": 323},
               {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
               {"name": "range", "size": 772},
               {"name": "select", "size": 296},
               {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
               {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
               {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
               {"name": "update", "size": 307},
               {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
               {"name": "where", "size": 299},
               {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
               {"name": "_", "size": 264}
              ]
          },
          {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
          {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
          {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
          {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
          {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
          {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
          {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
          {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
          {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
          {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
         ]
     },
     {
         "name": "scale",
         "children": [
          {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
          {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
          {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
          {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
          {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
          {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
          {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
          {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
          {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
          {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
         ]
     },
     {
         "name": "util",
         "children": [
          {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
          {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
          {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
          {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
          {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
          {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
          {
              "name": "heap",
              "children": [
               {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
               {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
              ]
          },
          {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
          {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
          {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
          {
              "name": "math",
              "children": [
               {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
               {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
               {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
              ]
          },
          {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
          {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
          {
              "name": "palette",
              "children": [
               {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
               {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
               {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
               {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
              ]
          },
          {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
          {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
          {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
          {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
          {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
         ]
     },
     {
         "name": "vis",
         "children": [
          {
              "name": "axis",
              "children": [
               {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
               {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
               {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
               {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
               {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
              ]
          },
          {
              "name": "controls",
              "children": [
               {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
               {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
               {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
               {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
               {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
               {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
               {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
               {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
               {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
               {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
               {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
              ]
          },
          {
              "name": "data",
              "children": [
               {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
               {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
               {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
               {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
               {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
               {
                   "name": "render",
                   "children": [
                    {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
                    {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
                    {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
                    {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
                   ]
               },
               {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
               {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
               {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
              ]
          },
          {
              "name": "events",
              "children": [
               {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
               {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
               {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
               {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
              ]
          },
          {
              "name": "legend",
              "children": [
               {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
               {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
               {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
              ]
          },
          {
              "name": "operator",
              "children": [
               {
                   "name": "distortion",
                   "children": [
                    {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
                    {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
                    {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "name": "encoder",
                   "children": [
                    {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
                    {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
                    {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
                    {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
                    {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "name": "filter",
                   "children": [
                    {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
                    {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
                    {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
                   ]
               },
               {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
               {
                   "name": "label",
                   "children": [
                    {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
                    {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
                    {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
                   ]
               },
               {
                   "name": "layout",
                   "children": [
                    {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
                    {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
                    {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
                    {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
                    {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
                    {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
                    {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
                    {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
                    {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
                    {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
                    {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
                    {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
                    {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
                    {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
                    {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
                   ]
               },
               {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
               {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
               {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
               {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
               {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
              ]
          },
          {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
         ]
     }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle? So that it would be easy for us to debug https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @williamcage cant really because of the json part, I tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: If you have JSON, host in plunker.. http://plnkr.co/edit/DLqarh1r7cZRjCXI8QwG?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append a container group element to the graph and set its class name as 'drawArea'. Now add following code.

```
d3.select("svg")
  .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.5, 5])
    .on("zoom", zoom));

function zoom() {
  var h = w = diameter * 2;
  var scale = d3.event.scale,
    translation = d3.event.translate,
    tbound = -h * scale,
    bbound = h * scale,
    lbound = -w * scale,
    rbound = w * scale;
  // limit translation to thresholds
  translation = [
    Math.max(Math.min(translation[0], rbound), lbound),
    Math.max(Math.min(translation[1], bbound), tbound)
  ];
  d3.select(".drawArea")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + translation + ")" +
      " scale(" + scale + ")");
}
```

**working Code Snippet:**

```js
var flare = {
  "name": "flare",
  "children": [{
    "name": "analytics",
    "children": [{
      "name": "cluster",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "CommunityStructure",
        "size": 3812
      }, {
        "name": "HierarchicalCluster",
        "size": 6714
      }, {
        "name": "MergeEdge",
        "size": 743
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "graph",
      "children": [{
        "name": "BetweennessCentrality",
        "size": 3534
      }, {
        "name": "LinkDistance",
        "size": 5731
      }, {
        "name": "MaxFlowMinCut",
        "size": 7840
      }, {
        "name": "ShortestPaths",
        "size": 5914
      }, {
        "name": "SpanningTree",
        "size": 3416
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "optimization",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AspectRatioBanker",
        "size": 7074
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "animate",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Easing",
      "size": 17010
    }, {
      "name": "FunctionSequence",
      "size": 5842
    }, {
      "name": "interpolate",
      "children": [{
        "name": "ArrayInterpolator",
        "size": 1983
      }, {
        "name": "ColorInterpolator",
        "size": 2047
      }, {
        "name": "DateInterpolator",
        "size": 1375
      }, {
        "name": "Interpolator",
        "size": 8746
      }, {
        "name": "MatrixInterpolator",
        "size": 2202
      }, {
        "name": "NumberInterpolator",
        "size": 1382
      }, {
        "name": "ObjectInterpolator",
        "size": 1629
      }, {
        "name": "PointInterpolator",
        "size": 1675
      }, {
        "name": "RectangleInterpolator",
        "size": 2042
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "ISchedulable",
      "size": 1041
    }, {
      "name": "Parallel",
      "size": 5176
    }, {
      "name": "Pause",
      "size": 449
    }, {
      "name": "Scheduler",
      "size": 5593
    }, {
      "name": "Sequence",
      "size": 5534
    }, {
      "name": "Transition",
      "size": 9201
    }, {
      "name": "Transitioner",
      "size": 19975
    }, {
      "name": "TransitionEvent",
      "size": 1116
    }, {
      "name": "Tween",
      "size": 6006
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "data",
    "children": [{
      "name": "converters",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Converters",
        "size": 721
      }, {
        "name": "DelimitedTextConverter",
        "size": 4294
      }, {
        "name": "GraphMLConverter",
        "size": 9800
      }, {
        "name": "IDataConverter",
        "size": 1314
      }, {
        "name": "JSONConverter",
        "size": 2220
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "DataField",
      "size": 1759
    }, {
      "name": "DataSchema",
      "size": 2165
    }, {
      "name": "DataSet",
      "size": 586
    }, {
      "name": "DataSource",
      "size": 3331
    }, {
      "name": "DataTable",
      "size": 772
    }, {
      "name": "DataUtil",
      "size": 3322
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "display",
    "children": [{
      "name": "DirtySprite",
      "size": 8833
    }, {
      "name": "LineSprite",
      "size": 1732
    }, {
      "name": "RectSprite",
      "size": 3623
    }, {
      "name": "TextSprite",
      "size": 10066
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "flex",
    "children": [{
      "name": "FlareVis",
      "size": 4116
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "physics",
    "children": [{
      "name": "DragForce",
      "size": 1082
    }, {
      "name": "GravityForce",
      "size": 1336
    }, {
      "name": "IForce",
      "size": 319
    }, {
      "name": "NBodyForce",
      "size": 10498
    }, {
      "name": "Particle",
      "size": 2822
    }, {
      "name": "Simulation",
      "size": 9983
    }, {
      "name": "Spring",
      "size": 2213
    }, {
      "name": "SpringForce",
      "size": 1681
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "query",
    "children": [{
      "name": "AggregateExpression",
      "size": 1616
    }, {
      "name": "And",
      "size": 1027
    }, {
      "name": "Arithmetic",
      "size": 3891
    }, {
      "name": "Average",
      "size": 891
    }, {
      "name": "BinaryExpression",
      "size": 2893
    }, {
      "name": "Comparison",
      "size": 5103
    }, {
      "name": "CompositeExpression",
      "size": 3677
    }, {
      "name": "Count",
      "size": 781
    }, {
      "name": "DateUtil",
      "size": 4141
    }, {
      "name": "Distinct",
      "size": 933
    }, {
      "name": "Expression",
      "size": 5130
    }, {
      "name": "ExpressionIterator",
      "size": 3617
    }, {
      "name": "Fn",
      "size": 3240
    }, {
      "name": "If",
      "size": 2732
    }, {
      "name": "IsA",
      "size": 2039
    }, {
      "name": "Literal",
      "size": 1214
    }, {
      "name": "Match",
      "size": 3748
    }, {
      "name": "Maximum",
      "size": 843
    }, {
      "name": "methods",
      "children": [{
        "name": "add",
        "size": 593
      }, {
        "name": "and",
        "size": 330
      }, {
        "name": "average",
        "size": 287
      }, {
        "name": "count",
        "size": 277
      }, {
        "name": "distinct",
        "size": 292
      }, {
        "name": "div",
        "size": 595
      }, {
        "name": "eq",
        "size": 594
      }, {
        "name": "fn",
        "size": 460
      }, {
        "name": "gt",
        "size": 603
      }, {
        "name": "gte",
        "size": 625
      }, {
        "name": "iff",
        "size": 748
      }, {
        "name": "isa",
        "size": 461
      }, {
        "name": "lt",
        "size": 597
      }, {
        "name": "lte",
        "size": 619
      }, {
        "name": "max",
        "size": 283
      }, {
        "name": "min",
        "size": 283
      }, {
        "name": "mod",
        "size": 591
      }, {
        "name": "mul",
        "size": 603
      }, {
        "name": "neq",
        "size": 599
      }, {
        "name": "not",
        "size": 386
      }, {
        "name": "or",
        "size": 323
      }, {
        "name": "orderby",
        "size": 307
      }, {
        "name": "range",
        "size": 772
      }, {
        "name": "select",
        "size": 296
      }, {
        "name": "stddev",
        "size": 363
      }, {
        "name": "sub",
        "size": 600
      }, {
        "name": "sum",
        "size": 280
      }, {
        "name": "update",
        "size": 307
      }, {
        "name": "variance",
        "size": 335
      }, {
        "name": "where",
        "size": 299
      }, {
        "name": "xor",
        "size": 354
      }, {
        "name": "_",
        "size": 264
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Minimum",
      "size": 843
    }, {
      "name": "Not",
      "size": 1554
    }, {
      "name": "Or",
      "size": 970
    }, {
      "name": "Query",
      "size": 13896
    }, {
      "name": "Range",
      "size": 1594
    }, {
      "name": "StringUtil",
      "size": 4130
    }, {
      "name": "Sum",
      "size": 791
    }, {
      "name": "Variable",
      "size": 1124
    }, {
      "name": "Variance",
      "size": 1876
    }, {
      "name": "Xor",
      "size": 1101
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "scale",
    "children": [{
      "name": "IScaleMap",
      "size": 2105
    }, {
      "name": "LinearScale",
      "size": 1316
    }, {
      "name": "LogScale",
      "size": 3151
    }, {
      "name": "OrdinalScale",
      "size": 3770
    }, {
      "name": "QuantileScale",
      "size": 2435
    }, {
      "name": "QuantitativeScale",
      "size": 4839
    }, {
      "name": "RootScale",
      "size": 1756
    }, {
      "name": "Scale",
      "size": 4268
    }, {
      "name": "ScaleType",
      "size": 1821
    }, {
      "name": "TimeScale",
      "size": 5833
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "util",
    "children": [{
      "name": "Arrays",
      "size": 8258
    }, {
      "name": "Colors",
      "size": 10001
    }, {
      "name": "Dates",
      "size": 8217
    }, {
      "name": "Displays",
      "size": 12555
    }, {
      "name": "Filter",
      "size": 2324
    }, {
      "name": "Geometry",
      "size": 10993
    }, {
      "name": "heap",
      "children": [{
        "name": "FibonacciHeap",
        "size": 9354
      }, {
        "name": "HeapNode",
        "size": 1233
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "IEvaluable",
      "size": 335
    }, {
      "name": "IPredicate",
      "size": 383
    }, {
      "name": "IValueProxy",
      "size": 874
    }, {
      "name": "math",
      "children": [{
        "name": "DenseMatrix",
        "size": 3165
      }, {
        "name": "IMatrix",
        "size": 2815
      }, {
        "name": "SparseMatrix",
        "size": 3366
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Maths",
      "size": 17705
    }, {
      "name": "Orientation",
      "size": 1486
    }, {
      "name": "palette",
      "children": [{
        "name": "ColorPalette",
        "size": 6367
      }, {
        "name": "Palette",
        "size": 1229
      }, {
        "name": "ShapePalette",
        "size": 2059
      }, {
        "name": "SizePalette",
        "size": 2291
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Property",
      "size": 5559
    }, {
      "name": "Shapes",
      "size": 19118
    }, {
      "name": "Sort",
      "size": 6887
    }, {
      "name": "Stats",
      "size": 6557
    }, {
      "name": "Strings",
      "size": 22026
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "vis",
    "children": [{
      "name": "axis",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Axes",
        "size": 1302
      }, {
        "name": "Axis",
        "size": 24593
      }, {
        "name": "AxisGridLine",
        "size": 652
      }, {
        "name": "AxisLabel",
        "size": 636
      }, {
        "name": "CartesianAxes",
        "size": 6703
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "controls",
      "children": [{
        "name": "AnchorControl",
        "size": 2138
      }, {
        "name": "ClickControl",
        "size": 3824
      }, {
        "name": "Control",
        "size": 1353
      }, {
        "name": "ControlList",
        "size": 4665
      }, {
        "name": "DragControl",
        "size": 2649
      }, {
        "name": "ExpandControl",
        "size": 2832
      }, {
        "name": "HoverControl",
        "size": 4896
      }, {
        "name": "IControl",
        "size": 763
      }, {
        "name": "PanZoomControl",
        "size": 5222
      }, {
        "name": "SelectionControl",
        "size": 7862
      }, {
        "name": "TooltipControl",
        "size": 8435
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "data",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Data",
        "size": 20544
      }, {
        "name": "DataList",
        "size": 19788
      }, {
        "name": "DataSprite",
        "size": 10349
      }, {
        "name": "EdgeSprite",
        "size": 3301
      }, {
        "name": "NodeSprite",
        "size": 19382
      }, {
        "name": "render",
        "children": [{
          "name": "ArrowType",
          "size": 698
        }, {
          "name": "EdgeRenderer",
          "size": 5569
        }, {
          "name": "IRenderer",
          "size": 353
        }, {
          "name": "ShapeRenderer",
          "size": 2247
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "ScaleBinding",
        "size": 11275
      }, {
        "name": "Tree",
        "size": 7147
      }, {
        "name": "TreeBuilder",
        "size": 9930
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "events",
      "children": [{
        "name": "DataEvent",
        "size": 2313
      }, {
        "name": "SelectionEvent",
        "size": 1880
      }, {
        "name": "TooltipEvent",
        "size": 1701
      }, {
        "name": "VisualizationEvent",
        "size": 1117
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "legend",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Legend",
        "size": 20859
      }, {
        "name": "LegendItem",
        "size": 4614
      }, {
        "name": "LegendRange",
        "size": 10530
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "operator",
      "children": [{
        "name": "distortion",
        "children": [{
          "name": "BifocalDistortion",
          "size": 4461
        }, {
          "name": "Distortion",
          "size": 6314
        }, {
          "name": "FisheyeDistortion",
          "size": 3444
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "encoder",
        "children": [{
          "name": "ColorEncoder",
          "size": 3179
        }, {
          "name": "Encoder",
          "size": 4060
        }, {
          "name": "PropertyEncoder",
          "size": 4138
        }, {
          "name": "ShapeEncoder",
          "size": 1690
        }, {
          "name": "SizeEncoder",
          "size": 1830
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "filter",
        "children": [{
          "name": "FisheyeTreeFilter",
          "size": 5219
        }, {
          "name": "GraphDistanceFilter",
          "size": 3165
        }, {
          "name": "VisibilityFilter",
          "size": 3509
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "IOperator",
        "size": 1286
      }, {
        "name": "label",
        "children": [{
          "name": "Labeler",
          "size": 9956
        }, {
          "name": "RadialLabeler",
          "size": 3899
        }, {
          "name": "StackedAreaLabeler",
          "size": 3202
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "layout",
        "children": [{
          "name": "AxisLayout",
          "size": 6725
        }, {
          "name": "BundledEdgeRouter",
          "size": 3727
        }, {
          "name": "CircleLayout",
          "size": 9317
        }, {
          "name": "CirclePackingLayout",
          "size": 12003
        }, {
          "name": "DendrogramLayout",
          "size": 4853
        }, {
          "name": "ForceDirectedLayout",
          "size": 8411
        }, {
          "name": "IcicleTreeLayout",
          "size": 4864
        }, {
          "name": "IndentedTreeLayout",
          "size": 3174
        }, {
          "name": "Layout",
          "size": 7881
        }, {
          "name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout",
          "size": 12870
        }, {
          "name": "PieLayout",
          "size": 2728
        }, {
          "name": "RadialTreeLayout",
          "size": 12348
        }, {
          "name": "RandomLayout",
          "size": 870
        }, {
          "name": "StackedAreaLayout",
          "size": 9121
        }, {
          "name": "TreeMapLayout",
          "size": 9191
        }]
      }, {
        "name": "Operator",
        "size": 2490
      }, {
        "name": "OperatorList",
        "size": 5248
      }, {
        "name": "OperatorSequence",
        "size": 4190
      }, {
        "name": "OperatorSwitch",
        "size": 2581
      }, {
        "name": "SortOperator",
        "size": 2023
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Visualization",
      "size": 16540
    }]
  }]
};

var diameter = 960;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([360, diameter / 2 - 120])
  .separation(function(a, b) {
    return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth;
  });

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI];
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", diameter)
  .attr("height", diameter - 150)
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "drawArea")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");


var root = flare;

var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
  links = tree.links(nodes);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", diagonal);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
  })
  /*this will change the color of the class node to red*/
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    var nodeSelection = d3.select(this).style("fill", "red");
  })
node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 4.5);

node.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".31em")
  .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
    return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "rotate(180)translate(-8)";
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

d3.select("svg")
  .call(d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.5, 5])
    .on("zoom", zoom));

function zoom() {
  var h = w = diameter * 2;
  var scale = d3.event.scale,
    translation = d3.event.translate,
    tbound = -h * scale,
    bbound = h * scale,
    lbound = (-w) * scale,
    rbound = (w) * scale;
  // limit translation to thresholds
  translation = [
    Math.max(Math.min(translation[0], rbound), lbound),
    Math.max(Math.min(translation[1], bbound), tbound)
  ];
  d3.select(".drawArea")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + translation + ")" +
      " scale(" + scale + ")");
}
```

```css
.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.node {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```